# Could not find the main class: com.complexible.stardog.cli.admin.CLI. Program will exit

Tags: semantic-web, stardog

I'm trying to install Stardog, but it sends me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/complexible/stardog/cli/admin/CLI, offset=6
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:540)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:79)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1038)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:429)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
>   Could not find the main class: com.complexible.stardog.cli.admin.CLI.  Program will exit.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors of this kind typically mean the code you are attempting for run is for a different version of Java than you are trying to run.

Stardog [requires Java 8](http://docs.stardog.com/#_requirements):

> Stardog runs on Java 8

So please ensure you are running it under Java 8, providing the output of `java -version` in your environment as part of your question would be helpful in determining if this is your problem.

Comment: It could be the problem...
 
java version "1.6.0"

Comment: Effectively, the problem was the Java version. Thank you.